# Скачивание изображения из блока с определённым классом

Tags: javascript, html

Знатоки, нужен хелп. Суть в том, как реализовать, ссылку на сайте, которая будет скачивать изображение из определённого класса. Допустим есть на сайте  и при нажатии, скачивается изображение, которое находится в div с классом .class . Может есть какая нибудь статья на эту тему, буду благодарен, в гугле ничего не нашел((

Comment: 10 секунд. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581379/how-to-save-the-contents-of-a-div-as-a-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я знаток))

Можно воспользоваться **fetch()**, чтоб отправить запрос и полученный результат записать в **Blob**, потом с помощью **window.URL.createObjectURL()** создаешь ссылку на загруженный файл в кеше браузера. Потом с помощью **document.createElement('a')** создаешь элемент  на странице и в атрибут href помещаешь созданный ранее url через **createObjectURL()**, и потом с помощью **click()** нажимаешь на него.

Вот я вырезал из своей программки код, должен работать (использовал JQuery):

```
$('.image_class').unbind().on('click', function(){
        fetch($(this).attr('src')).then(resp => resp.blob()).then(blob => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.style.display = 'none';
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'file_name';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        });
    });
```

Если ты делаешь для хрома это, то можно воспользоваться chrome.downloads.download():

```
  $('.image_class').unbind().on('click', function(){
     chrome.downloads.download({
        url: $(this).attr('src'),
        filename: 'filename',
        saveAs: "если нужно скачивать туда куда выбрал пользователь пишешь true, если в дефолтную папку для загрузок то false"
     });
  });
```